# fgets is limited to 1024 bytes - what can I use instead?

Tags: c

I want to read from user's input string of size 16000bytes. `fgets` only reads 1024  bytes. What can I use instead? I am writing in c and this is my code right now. Is it that I am not using malloc?

```
char str[16392];

while(fprintf(stderr, "> "), fgets(str, 16392, stdin), !feof(stdin)) { }
```

Also, readline seems to work.

```
  while(line = readline("> "), !feof(stdin)) {
    printf("You entered: %s\n", line);
    free(line);  
  }
```

Comment: You can use `fgets()` 16 times.

Comment: `fgets()` has no limit. `char buffer[100000]; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);`

Comment: Remember, `fgets()` is for getting *lines*. If your user is presenting you with a 16,000 character line, you might want to sit them down and have a talk to them about it.

Comment: Your use of `feof()` is wrong! See [`while( !feof( file ) )` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: `fgets()` doesn't read strings, it reads lines. You probably have some line separator in your input string and `fgets()` is only reading until that point because of it.

Comment: What's with the repeated horrible abuse of the comma operator, by the way?

Comment: @Paul Griffiths, the Polish novelist Jerzy Andrzejewski in “The Gates of Paradise” wrote a 158-page run-on. It's comprised of two sentences and the 2nd is only five words long.  Thankfully it was pre-computer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not replace `fgets()` with a worse option. `fgets()` has no limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    char *buffer;
    size_t size;
    size = 10000000; /* 10m */
    buffer = malloc(size);
    if (!buffer) /* error */;
    if (fgets(buffer, size, stdin) == NULL) /* error */;
    // ...
    free(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wondering is it important to use malloc for the buffer?

Comment: If you don't, your buffer will be stored in the call stack. The call stack has a limited size, by default 1MB in most compilers, you don't want to abuse its space.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is an implementation where fgets() has a 1024 byte limit; however, this is not something I have seen before.

An alternative might be fread().